# Apache as a reverse proxy with restricting allowed hosts

Tags: apache-2.4, reverse-proxy

I've come up with apache configuration that does reverse-proxy for an internal owncloud installation. It works very well and now I'd like to **restrict hosts by IP**, that would have access to this reverse-proxied host, but I noticed 2 things (example config of the host doing the proxying):

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
  # I put below line here but it seems it isn't used when reverse-proxying
  DocumentRoot "c:/apache/owncloud"
  # this host is going to answer to The World to requests to owncloud
  ServerName cloud.example.com:443
  ServerAdmin kitet@example.com
  ErrorLog "c:/apache/logs/ssl-owncloud-error.log"
  TransferLog "c:/apache/logs/ssl-owncloud-access.log"
  # the actual host with owncloud is reachable from intranet by this name
  ProxyPass "/" "https://cloud.example.com/"
  ProxyPassReverse "/" "https://cloud.example.com/"
  # This is important, the Directory section, I imagined this would work...
  <Directory "c:/apache/owncloud">
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride FileInfo
    Require IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
    Require IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
    Require all denied
  </Directory>
  SSLEngine on
  SSLCertificateFile "c:/apache/ssl/server.pem"
  SSLCertificateKeyFile "c:/apache/ssl/privkey.decr.key"
  SSLProxyEngine On
</VirtualHost>
```

**1)** I've put the Directory section and thought it would be respected, but it isn't.

**2)** Naturally the proxied machine (owncloud host) has no idea that in reality host external to our LAN pulled the page, in access logs it's only showing IP of the proxy, so I can't do the restricting there.

Please share your knowledge as to where do I setup IP based restrictions because these above don't work and effectively whole world can see owncloud as it is.

Comment: I'm not quite sure what you're asking but if you want to apply restrictions to a reverse proxy you should probably set both the ProxyPass and ACL's  in a `Location` container.

Comment: Right, I've significantly shortended the question to focus on relevant info only. Yes, I'd like to apply restrictions and I will try with `Location` later today

Answer (score 0):

Since a ProxyPass does not map requests to the local file system setting access controls in a `Directory` block does not work. You'll need to set them in a `Location` container, i.e. use something like this:

```
<Location />
    ProxyPass  "https://cloud.example.com/"
    ProxyPassReverse "https://cloud.example.com/"
    <RequireAll>
       Require IP xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx
       Require IP yyy.yyy.yyy.yyy
       Require all denied
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

Comment: afaik that set of Require directives would need to be enclosed in a <RequireAll> tag.